# how To manage middlewares using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have create 3 users('Super-Admin','Branch-Admin','User'). I am trying to do that when ' Super-Admin' is login its not gone to the other 2 users dashboard Users('Branch-Admin,User'). But its show a page with "Too many redirect " and when i give URL of any other user in browser it redirect its dashboard from its own dashboard. And same like these other 2 users????

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isNotAdmin']], function(){
        Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@getIndex');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isBranchAdmin']], function(){
        Route::get('/branch','BranchController@gettIndex');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isAdmin']], function(){
    Route::get('/Super/admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');
        });
```

View:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'User')
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/home">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/contact">
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/about">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/blog">
                    Blog
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/faqs">
                    FAQs
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'Admin')
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'companies') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/companies">
                    Companies
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'branchies') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/branchies">
                    Branchies
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'BranchAdmin')
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'medicines') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/medicines">
                    Medicines
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'stock') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/stock">
                    Stock_details
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @endif
</div>
```

Middlewares:

BranchAdmin:

```
class BranchAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'BranchAdmin'){
            return redirect('/branch/'.Auth::user()->branch->id);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

UserIsAdmin:

```
class UserIsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'Admin'){
            return redirect('/Super/admin');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

UserIsNotAdmin:

```
class UserIsNotAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'User'){
            return redirect('/profile');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your middleware logic does not seem to be right. I think you should definitely have too many redirects because of that. I take one middleware as an example.

```
class UserIsNotAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'User'){
            return redirect('/profile');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

What you are saying is that

```
If the user is of type 'User', always redirect them to '/profile'
```

Therefore, if a user of type 'User' goes to `http://website/profile`, it keeps redirecting them to profile over and over again.

What you should do is actually do what middleware are for: Stop intruders :). E.g: in UserIsNotAdmin middleware, do this

```
if( !Auth::user()->type === 'User' ){
    redirect('/home');
}
return $next($request);
```

Translates into

```
if the user IS NOT of type 'User', send them home. Else, let them in.
```